# Why is GeoNetwork not displaying any maps?

Tags: mysql, geonetwork, centos

I've just installed GeoNetwork 2.6.4 on CentOS 6.2 using MySQL as the database backend.  Now, when I go to the web interface, I see the main web site, but no maps are displayed.  On the geonetwork machine (actually it's a VM) I see them, but over the network I don't.

Can anyone think of anything I should check or change? I set the jetty.xml file to listen on all interfaces and turned iptables off (it was on by default) so that I could access the web site at all.

Answer (score 1):

I (or rather one of my co-workers ) figured out the solution.  In the config-gui.xml file, there are entries for http:// localhost :8080/geonetwork/web - changing these to just /geonetwork/web and restarting the server fixed the issue. (I put the additional spaces around localhost so it wouldn't appear as a web address!)